# Retrieving query from URL

Tags: php

So I need to retrieve a query string from the URL except it doesn't seem to be retrieving anything. There are various services on a service page, when a service is clicked on you are taken to the order page and this page has the query at the end (order.php?service=bronze). When the confirm order button is clicked, it is directed to a php validation script which aside from validation gets all the information and stores it into session variables for the confirmation page. This includes getting the query data from the order page but the variable is empty. Am I unable to retrieve the query string after going to the order validation page? How else can I get the query?

service.php -> order.php?query -> order-validation.php -> confirmation.php[need query data on this page]

```
$orderservice = htmlspecialchars($_GET["service"]);
```

I put:

```
    <input name="order-service" id="service" 
    value="<?php $orderservice = htmlspecialchars($_GET["service"]);?>" />
```

into the form and it still comes up empty =(

The form uses the post method, is that why I can't get the data?

Comment: Store the service in a hidden input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "echo" the value :

```
<input name="order-service" id="service" 
    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["service"]);?>" />
```